# insert contains of a column into a another new one in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

Hello I want to insert into a new column 2019 the population of each town which is 2% higher than 2018.
I tried this bu that didn't work

````
```DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE LoopDemo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
        SET x = 1;

        WHILE x <= (SELECT count(*) from commune_recensement_population) DO
             update commune_recensement_population set pmun19 = x;
             SET  x = x + 1;
        END  WHILE;

END$$

CALL LoopDemo();```
````

Comment: The SQL query you’ve posted does not match the expected result. All you’re doing is setting the value of an incrementing integer. Where is the 2% population growth number coming from?

Comment: Sorry I  took the wrong files.

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE LoopDemo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE y DOUBLE;
        SET x = 1;
        SET Y = SELECT pmun18 from base_pop_historiques_1876_2018;

        WHILE x <= (SELECT count(*) from commune_recensement_population) DO
         set y = floor(y * 1.02);
             update commune_recensement_population set pmun19 = y;
             SET  x = x + 1;
        END  WHILE;

END$$

CALL LoopDemo();

Comment: This is going to update all records in `commune_recensement_population` 146 times with the same math. Are you just adding 2% to every record, or do you need to add 2% to *specific* records? Trying to understand the end goal … 

Comment: In fact there's 69940 city who had different population and I must add with a SQl request a new column name 2019 who will have 69940 new different data who will be 2% higher than their pop of 2018. I don't know if I'm clear, excuse me I'm french and my english is very bad